# Determining possible arrangements of colored balls

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem I have been working on recently. I have $k$ balls in $\ell \leq k$ different colors. In how many ways can I arrange these balls (imagine arranging them in a line) such that no two balls of the same color are next to each other? It would be great if someone could help me!

Comment: The answer depends on the number of balls having the same color.

Comment: yes we dont know that , we only know that there are L different colors . So I do not know if a general formula can be derived in this case for the possible arrangements .

Comment: You can derive it assuming there are $k_i$ balls painted with the $i$-th color. And of course $k_1+\cdots + k_l = k$. But still I don't know if a closed expression exists, probably not.

Comment: Use PIE on the set $A_1\cup A_2\cup \cdots\cup A_l$ where $A_i$ is the set of arrangements in which there exists at least one pair of adjacent balls of color $i$ and then subtract the cardinality of that set from the total number of arrangements

Comment: [PIE](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: Take $k=5$ and $l=2$. If the split is $4,1$ then there are no ways to do it, and if it is $3,2$ then there is $1$ way (xyxyx) to do it. So the answer depends on knowing something about how many of each color you have.

Comment: yes everyone , i realised it is only possible if you know the number of each colored ball.